# Why I can't enable DTDs support in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, dtd

I'm working with DTD in T-SQL and for the following code:

```sql
use customers;

DECLARE @xmlData XML;
SET @xmlData = '<!DOCTYPE replace [<!ENTITY example "Doe"> ]><customer><name>John Doe</name><address>123 Main St, Anytown, USA</address><salary>&example</salary></customer>';

INSERT INTO customers (name, address, salary)
SELECT
    T.c.value('(name/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
    T.c.value('(address/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
    T.c.value('(salary/text())[1]', 'DECIMAL(18, 2)')
FROM @xmlData.nodes('/customers/customer') AS T(c);
```

I got the following error message.

> Parsing XML with internal subset DTDs not allowed. Use `CONVERT` with style option 2 to enable limited internal subset DTD support.

I tried to fix the convert function:

```sql
SET @xmlData = CONVERT(XML, @xmlData, 2);

Select CONVERT(XML, @xmlData, 2);
```

And nothing seems to fix the issue. Can someone give me some hints?

Comment: DTDs were replaced by XML Schema in the early 2000s, as part of the SOAP and Web Services standardization. If you want to validate XML data in SQL Server you'll have to use [XML Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-schema-collections-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 1):

Trying to `CONVERT` the variable after you've already failed to assign it won't work. You need to explicitly `CONVERT` the literal string you have:

```sql
DECLARE @xmlData XML;
SET @xmlData = CONVERT(xml,'<!DOCTYPE replace [<!ENTITY example "Doe"> ]><customer><name>John Doe</name><address>123 Main St, Anytown, USA</address><salary>&example</salary></customer>',2);
```

This, however, will give you a different error (and print statement):

> Msg 9411, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
> XML parsing: line 1, character 137, semicolon expected
>
> XML DTD has been stripped from one or more XML fragments.  External subsets, if any, have been ignored.

This error is because of `<salary>&example</salary>`; the ampersand needs to be escaped as `&amp;`. If you fix that at your source, then it works and the DTD is stripped:

```sql
DECLARE @xmlData XML;
SET @xmlData = CONVERT(xml,'<!DOCTYPE replace [<!ENTITY example "Doe"> ]><customer><name>John Doe</name><address>123 Main St, Anytown, USA</address><salary>&amp;example</salary></customer>',2);
```

Answer (score -1):

So, the problem with my code sample is the

```
DECLARE @xmlData XML;
```

It should be an `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.